# .htaccess rewrite for all but domain itself to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

There exists a blog at domain.com

I wish to do a 301 redirect on anything that is after `domain.com/[category/[post-name]` to `domain.com/blog/[category]/[post-name]`

The key here is when someone hits `domain.com` they just stay there. Only if there's any reference to posts within `domain.com` that I wish for the redirect to work.

Will hold this for at most 6 months, until SEO settles, and then remove the redirect.

What is the best way of achieving this with .htaccess ?

The current one is as follows:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>`

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule /(\w+)/([^/]+)  /blog/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```